# как после 400 пикселей уменьшить всю html страницу кросбраузерно,чтоб она уменьшалась как ctrl -?

Tags: javascript, html, css

как после 400 пикселей уменьшить всю  html страницу кросбраузерно,чтоб она уменьшалась как ctrl- ?

Answer (score 3):

Can I use:

1. [zoom](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom)
2. [css-mediaqueries](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    zoom: .9
  }
}
```

Comment: А как с фаирфоксом быть ,он zoom не читает?

Comment: На крайняк `transform: scale()` ещё есть, но это далёко не альтернатива. Если вы таким образом хотите сделать сайт адаптивным, то лучше не стоит. Лучше работайте над отображением каждого компонента интерфейса отдельно в зависимости от размера окна.